# how to find a counterexample of this statement?

Tags: limits

[image]

I want to use the Harmonic series to construct it but I don't know how to do this（bn is an arbitrary increasing sequence in N{0}）

Comment: What is a negative sample?  Do you mean counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

We claim that there exists no such counterexample. Let $b_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence and let $a_n$ be a sequence satisfying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{b_n}-a_n=0\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{b_n} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n} $. For the sake of contradiction, assume $a_n$ diverges. That is, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n}=\infty.$ Then $a_n$ is strictly increasing for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $b_n$ be the sequence $a_N, a_{N+1}, a_{N+2}, ...$ We must have that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{b_n}-a_n =0\Rightarrow\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n}-a_n =0,$ which is a contradiction as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n}-a_n >0.$ Thus, we have that $a_n$ converges.

Comment: however it was the sum that diverges

Comment: bn is an arbitrary increasing sequence in N{0}

Comment: this bn should be arbitrary

Comment: @user681240you mean that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{b_n} -a_n = 0$ for **any** strictly increasing sequence $b_n$, then $a_n$ converges, right?

Comment: @user681240sorry for not giving the answer you wanted the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_n = n$ and $a_n = n$. Then $b_n$ is strictly increasing and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a_{b_n}-a_n = a_n - a_n = 0$, so $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{b_n}-a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$$ but $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty$$